# Uso das palavras Mau vs. Mal

Tags: homofonia

Sempre tenho muito duvida sobre o uso correto destas duas palavras.
Alguém poderia dar uma explicação clara, exemplificada?

Comment: Joás, bem-vindo ao site. A tua pergunta já existe, e já tem duas respostas. Segue o link no comentário do Guilherme, acima. A regra aqui no site é não repetir perguntas. Vale a pena, antes de fazer uma pergunta, procurar pelas palavras chave na caixa "Search Q&A", canto superior direito.

Comment: Um truque que funciona na dúvida :
Quando se usa maL, contraste com bEm Quando se usa maU, contraste com bOm
(Observe o formato parecido do L e E; e U e O)

Comment: Ok meu amigo obrigado!